# SSKeychain the authenticity of "AppName" cannot be verified

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, osx-mountain-lion, sskeychain

I've recently implemented SSKeychain in my application, every single time i try to access values from the keychain i get prompted to give permission to access the keychain with the message "the authenticity of "AppName" cannot be verified. Do you want to allow access to this item?

i've chosen "Always Allow" about a gillion times but it still prompts me no matter what. its really annoying and looks incredibly unprofessional. pulling my hair out trying to figure out what im doing wrong or how to fix it. to save a password im using

[SSKeychain setPassword:self.passwordField.stringValue forService:@"AppName" account:self.loginField.stringValue];

and to retrieve it

[SSKeychain passwordForService:@"AppName" account:self.loginField.stringValue];

any thoughts?

Comment: Did you figure out this issue? Having the same problem.

Comment: yes, it was because my application wasn't being code signed. really stupid imo.